# How does Doctrine determine the order to commit (and how to troubleshoot it)

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am adding fixtures using theofidry/AliceBundle which in turn uses nelmio/alice.

One of my entities is Vendor and another is VendorUser and VendorUser holds the PK of Vendor and thus Vendor must be committed before VendorUser.  Even though I don't think it matters, I took steps to ensure they are persisted in the correct order and have verified that Vendor was persisted before VendorUser.  But then when flushed, I get a not-null constraint error stating the vendor is not set in vendorUser.

I look into it and see that `UnitOfWork::commit()` calls `UnitOfWork::getCommitOrder()` which also shows that VendorUser is scheduled to be committed before Vendor.  Going down the rabbit hole, I see that `UnitOfWork::getCommitOrder()` calls `UnitOfWork::getCommitOrderCalculator()` which returns a new `CommitOrderCalculator`, which has the following comment in its source code:

> CommitOrderCalculator implements topological sorting, which is an
> ordering algorithm for directed graphs (DG) and/or directed acyclic
> graphs (DAG) by using a depth-first searching (DFS) to traverse the
> graph built in memory.  This algorithm have a linear running time
> based on nodes (V) and dependency between the nodes (E), resulting in
> a computational complexity of O(V + E).

I've tried to figure out how this class works but am not making much progress.  Are there any tools to analyze what it is doing?  How does Doctrine determine the order to commit records?  How can I gleam information about why it is doing it the way it is so I may troubleshoot?  I expect that Vendor has some not-null property which isn't yet set, however, for the life of me I can't figure it out.

**EDIT**  It appears to either be a Doctrine bug or probably more likely my schema is not supported.  I believe the cause is two entities have references to each other (users have an organization, all entities except for Tenant must belong to a Tenant, and all entities have a createBy and updateBy blameable field) and Doctrine doesn't know which one to do first.  There is a correct order, but it is based on business logic and not the database schema, so Doctrine alone can't figure it out.  Is there a way to instruct Doctrine the order to commit?  Below is a test script which manually creates the entities without using fixtures or blamable.  As seen by the output from UnitOfWork's commit order, it will clearly fail as concrete classes are committed before their inherited parents. Any recommendations?

```php
    private function testSomething()
    {
        $manager = $this->managerRegistry->getManager();
        $rootUser = $manager->getRepository(TestTenantUser::class)->find(new NilUlid);
        
        $tenant = new TestTenant;
        $vendor = new TestVendor;
        $tenant->addVendor($vendor);
        $tenantUser = new TestTenantUser;
        $vendorUser = new TestVendorUser;
        $tenant->addUser($tenantUser);
        $vendor->addUser($vendorUser);

        // Simulating being set by blamable listner.
        $tenant->setCreateBy($rootUser)->setUpdateBy($rootUser);
        $vendor->setCreateBy($rootUser)->setUpdateBy($rootUser);
        $tenantUser->setCreateBy($rootUser)->setUpdateBy($rootUser);
        $vendorUser->setCreateBy($rootUser)->setUpdateBy($rootUser);

        // Technically only need to persist tenant since others will cascade persist, but just to be double sure.
        $manager->persist($tenant);
        $manager->persist($vendor);
        $manager->persist($tenantUser);
        $manager->persist($vendorUser);
        printf('%-30s with ID %s has organization %s'.PHP_EOL, get_class($tenantUser), $tenantUser->getId()->toRfc4122(), $tenantUser->getOrganization()->getId()->toRfc4122());
        printf('%-30s with ID %s has organization %s'.PHP_EOL, get_class($vendorUser), $vendorUser->getId()->toRfc4122(), $vendorUser->getOrganization()->getId()->toRfc4122());
        try {
            $manager->flush();
        }
        catch(\Exception $e) {
            exit($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

```php
class UnitOfWork implements PropertyChangedListener
{
    public function commit($entity = null)
    {

        ...
        $commitOrder = $this->getCommitOrder();

        echo(PHP_EOL.'UnitOfWork::commit() $this->getCommitOrder(): '.PHP_EOL);
        foreach($commitOrder as $class){
            echo($class->getName().PHP_EOL);
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

```
App\Entity\Test\TestTenantUser with ID 0182f48a-5778-0cb2-d24d-7840c74773b1 has organization 0182f48a-5778-0cb2-d24d-7840c74773b0
App\Entity\Test\TestVendorUser with ID 0182f48a-5779-dc20-c1d4-9ec596c1ee6d has organization 0182f48a-5778-0cb2-d24d-7840c74773b2

UnitOfWork::commit() $this->getCommitOrder(): 
App\Entity\Test\TestTenant
App\Entity\Test\TestVendorUser
App\Entity\Test\TestAbstractUser
App\Entity\Test\TestAbstractOrganization
App\Entity\Test\TestTenantUser
App\Entity\Test\TestVendor


An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column "organization_id" of relation "test_abstract_user" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (0182f48a-5779-dc20-c1d4-9ec596c1ee6d, null, 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, 2022-08-31 08:34:43, 2022-08-31 08:34:43, vendor).
```

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace App\Entity\Test;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity]
class TestTenant extends TestAbstractOrganization
{
    #[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: TestVendor::class, mappedBy: 'tenant', cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    private Collection $vendors;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->vendors = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addUser(TestAbstractUser $user): self
    {    
       $user->setTenant($this);
       return parent::addUser($user);
    }

    public function getVendors(): Collection
    {
        return $this->vendors;
    }

    public function addVendor(TestVendor $vendor): self
    {
        if (!$this->vendors->contains($vendor)) {
            $this->vendors[] = $vendor;
            $vendor->setTenant($this);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function removeVendor(TestVendor $vendor): self
    {
        if (!$this->vendors->removeElement($vendor)) {
            return $this;
        }
        if ($vendor->getTenant() !== $this) {
            return $this;
        }
        $vendor->setTenant(null);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace App\Entity\Test;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity]
#[ORM\AssociationOverrides([new ORM\AssociationOverride(name: 'tenant', joinTable: new ORM\JoinTable(name: 'tenant'), inversedBy: 'vendors')])]
class TestVendor extends TestAbstractOrganization
{
    use TestBelongsToTenantTrait;

    public function addUser(TestAbstractUser $user): self
    {    
       $user->setTenant($this->getTenant());
       return parent::addUser($user);
    }
}
```

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace App\Entity\Test;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity]
#[ORM\InheritanceType(value: 'JOINED')]
#[ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name: 'discriminator', type: 'string')]
#[ORM\DiscriminatorMap(value: ['tenant' => TestTenant::class, 'vendor' => TestVendor::class])]
abstract class TestAbstractOrganization extends TestAbstractEntity
{
    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'organization', targetEntity: TestAbstractUser::class, cascade: ['persist', 'remove'], orphanRemoval: true)]
    protected Collection $users;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getUsers(): Collection
    {
        return $this->users;
    }

    public function addUser(TestAbstractUser $user): self
    {    
       if (!$this->users->contains($user)) {
            $this->users[] = $user;
       }
       $user->setOrganization($this);
       return $this;
    }

    public function removeUser(TestAbstractUser $user): self
    {
        if ($this->users->removeElement($user)) {
            if ($user->getOrganization() === $this) {
                $user->setOrganization(null);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace App\Entity\Test;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity]
class TestTenantUser extends TestAbstractUser
{
    use TestBelongsToTenantTrait;
}
```

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace App\Entity\Test;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity]
class TestVendorUser extends TestAbstractUser
{
    use TestBelongsToTenantTrait;
}
```

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Entity\Test;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity]
#[ORM\InheritanceType(value: 'JOINED')]
#[ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name: 'discriminator', type: 'string')]
#[ORM\DiscriminatorMap(value: ['tenant' => TestTenantUser::class, 'vendor' => TestVendorUser::class])]
abstract class TestAbstractUser extends TestAbstractEntity
{
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'users')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false, onDelete: 'CASCADE')]
    protected ?TestAbstractOrganization $organization=null;

    public function getOrganization(): TestAbstractOrganization
    {
        return $this->organization;
    }

    public function setOrganization(TestAbstractOrganization $organization): self
    {
        $this->organization = $organization;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);
namespace App\Entity\Test;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use DateTime;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Symfony\Component\Uid\Ulid;
use App\Doctrine\IdGenerator\UlidGenerator;

abstract class TestAbstractEntity
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'ulid', unique: true)]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'CUSTOM')]
    #[ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class: UlidGenerator::class)]
    protected ?Ulid $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'datetime')]
    //#[Gedmo\Timestampable(on: 'create')]
    protected ?DateTime $createAt = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: TestAbstractUser::class)]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    //#[Gedmo\Blameable(on: 'create')]
    protected ?TestAbstractUser $createBy = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'datetime')]
    //#[Gedmo\Timestampable(on: 'update')]
    protected ?DateTime $updateAt = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: TestAbstractUser::class)]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    //#[Gedmo\Blameable(on: 'update')]
    protected ?TestAbstractUser $updateBy = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->createAt = new DateTime();
        $this->updateAt = new DateTime();
    }

    public function getId(): ?Ulid
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getCreateAt(): ?DateTime
    {
        return $this->createAt;
    }

    public function getCreateBy(): ?TestAbstractUser
    {
        return $this->createBy;
    }

    // Shouldn't need this?  Maybe only by HelpDesk?
    public function setCreateAt(DateTime $date): self
    {
        $this->createAt = $date;
        
        return $this;
    }
    public function setCreateBy(TestAbstractUser $user): self
    {
        $this->createBy = $user;
        
        return $this;
    }
    public function getUpdateAt(): ?DateTime
    {
        return $this->updateAt;
    }

    public function getUpdateBy(): ?TestAbstractUser
    {
        return $this->updateBy;
    }

    // Shouldn't need this?  Maybe only by HelpDesk?
    public function setUpdateAt(DateTime $date): self
    {
        $this->updateAt = $date;
        
        return $this;
    }
    public function setUpdateBy(TestAbstractUser $user): self
    {
        $this->updateBy = $user;
        
        return $this;
    }
}
```

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace App\Entity\Test;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

trait TestBelongsToTenantTrait
{
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: TestTenant::class)]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false, onDelete: 'CASCADE')]
    protected ?TestTenant $tenant=null;

    public function getTenant(): ?TestTenant
    {
        return $this->tenant;
    }

    public function setTenant(TestTenant $tenant): self
    {
        $this->tenant = $tenant;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: please add the code for the fixture.

Comment: @Toskan  To isolate the problem, I am creating the entities manually instead of with fixtures and still get the same behavior.   Please see my above added code.  Thank you